# UITableViewCell behave differently in iOS7 and iOS8 simulator using xcode6 beta6 interface builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6-beta6

Please see below 3 table view cells in the same app, the height of the cell is 54 in interface builder, the border is created using CAShapeLayer in code with a height of 44. Since I switched from xcode5 to xcode6 during the project development, so part of the uitableviewcell is created in xcode5 and part in xcode6, and there are cells that are created in xcode5 and later changed in xcode6.

image1. created using *xcode5*, the desired style
[image: uitableviewcell built in xcode5 interface builder]

image2. created using *xcode6 beta6*, displayed in iOS8 simulator, `disclosure indicator` misplaced, and text are offseted
[image: uitableviewcell built in xcode6 beta6, displayed in iOS8 simulator]

image3. the same cell of image2 using *xcode6 beta6*, but running in iOS7.1 device, `disclosure indicator` misplaced
[image: uitableviewcell built in xcode6 beta6, displayed in iOS7.1 device]

I compared all the settings of the uitableviewcell in interface builder, and find NO differences.

And I compared the source file of xxx.storyboard, and finally got the different point:

**case1**: the 'tableViewCell' tag, the *xcode5* version is:

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="none" accessoryType="disclosureIndicator" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="xxCell" rowHeight="54" id="far-Kn-fRP" customClass="xxCell">
  <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="119" width="320" height="54"/>
```

**case2**: the 'tableViewCell' tag, the *xcode6 beta6* version is below, NOTICE, the < rect key="frame" ...> is missing when creating a new uitableviewcell

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="none" accessoryType="disclosureIndicator" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="xxxCell" rowHeight="54" id="eav-sl-Yrd" customClass="xxxCell">
```

**case3**: the scenario in image2 and image3 is a uitableviewcell created in *xcode5* with default height of 44, and modified in *xcode6 beta6* to change the height to 54, and the source is:

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="none" accessoryType="disclosureIndicator" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="xxxCell" rowHeight="54" id="eav-sl-Yrd" customClass="xxxCell">
  <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="119" width="320" height="44"/>
```

As a conclusion, it seems that xcode6 beta6 is not handling the < rect key="frame" ...> tag in the .storyboard file, and will cause misplace of uitableviewcell.

Added: In all of the above scenarios, the code has implemented `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, and returned 54.

**My Questions are**:

1. I didn't find how to place `disclosure indicator` at the same place as xcode5
2. Is the missing of < rect key="frame" ...> a bug or replaced by other tags in xcode6? Possible related to the cell auto sizing feature in iOS8?
3. Is there other solutions to make uitableviewcell right? I'm currently manually modifying .storyboard file to add < rect key="frame" ...> tag for each newly created uitableviewcell using xcode6 beta6, and it is error prone.

Thanks.

Comment: How is the content of the cell constructed? Is everything inside the `contentView`? Are there constraints? Are those constraints connected to the _cell_ or to the `contentView` (that's very important)? Also, are you aware of the new iOS 8 automatic row height feature? It might be affecting the vertical layout of the cell.

Comment: "I'm currently manually modifying .storyboard file, and it is error prone." It sounds to me like you're constructing the cell in a faulty way.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your quick comment. The 2 labels are placed as subview of 'contentView', and the constraints are set relative to 'superView' (the contentView in this case) for leading and centerY, with fixed width and height. My last word "I'm currently manually modifying .storyboard file" means that I had to manually add < rect key="frame" ...> for the uitableviewcell created using xcode6 beta6 interface builder. The 'new iOS 8 automatic row height feature' is new to me, I'll check that. Thanks.

Comment: @matt thanks for the information of 'new iOS 8 automatic row height feature', I checked it just now, and it is awesome. But my project needs to support iOS7, so I had implemented `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for all uitableview already. And the examples in my questions return 54 in funciton: `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

About misplacing your border CAShapeLayer - you need to override `layoutSubviews` function of your custom cell class and update frame of layer accordingly.

Also don't use cell's bounds property, because it is a different than frame size:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.borderLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
}
```

About offset for the disclosure indicator - I can't reproduce issue from your screenshot...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the issue here is the misplace of the text and disclosure indicator, not the CAShapeLayer. BTW, I never see this issue after I use xcode6.1